# Why do people have outdoor pump houses for their well?

Tags: water, well, well-pump

Why do people build outdoor pump houses for their well? I have read it is to help prevent the components from freezing but by putting them outside all they do is freeze. Every winter they freeze and you need to go outside and unfreeze it occasionally or keep the water running during the night.

Why wouldn't you just put what is in the pump house inside of the house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why wouldn't you just put what is in the pump house inside of the house?

You'd have to ask each person who chose otherwise. There's no single blanket answer.

For what it's worth, my well does *not* have a pump house. Everything but the submersible pump (which is at the bottom of the well, far below any risk of freezing) is in the house.

For the most part, this is a positive thing. The pressure tank, pressure sender, and pump controller are all inside where it's easy to monitor them and do any maintenance if required. Likewise the whole-house filtration system.

We don't need or have a cistern/storage for the well water. But certainly one reason one might choose to have a well house is to provide a place for water storage to live. A low-producing well could require a fairly large storage tank, something not feasible to put in a house.

Even in my own situation, there is certainly one element to the whole system that makes me regret having it in the house: the filtration system includes a couple of flow-powered pumps to draw solutions (bleach, and soda ash, for water treatment purposes), and these pumps are *really* loud and annoying. For now, I put up with them because the alternative would be more annoying and potentially expensive (manganese, which would stain all the fixtures/sinks/bowls/etc.), but I continue to look for alternatives that won't be so noisy.

I'd much rather have that noise outside in a well house, than in my mechanical room where I can still hear them clicking away any time the water's running.

So, there's at least two things I can think of that could cause someone to prefer to keep the water-related equipment outside, instead of in the house.

The issues mentioned in the other answers, I suppose they could apply to different kinds of wells. I don't see how they would apply to the deep submersible-pump well I have though (obviously, since my system works fine with everything in the house, other than the pump).

Answer (score 5):

The well isn't always close to the house.

And pumps don't do well with sucking water out of a distant well, priming will be an issue.

If you have freezing issues then you should add some insulation to your pump house and/or you can add a heat source controlled by a thermostat that prevents the temperature inside the well house (or at least the water lines before they disappear into the ground) from dropping below 0°C.

Comment: So from the sound of it some pump houses have the pump in the pump house instead of down inside the well? How far is considered far? 50-100ft?

Comment: Just have to comment:  Above ground centrifugal pumps can theoretically only draw water down to about 32 feet.  Realistically, 25-26 feet is the max. In my neck of the woods, nearly all wells have submersible pumps which can pump water from substantial depths since it pushes the water up rather than sucks it up.   ....now the tongue in cheek remark: Pump houses make great places to store your lawnmower, pressure washer, leaf blower, etc.!  LOL

Answer (score 2):

Wells typically have pumps, filters, tank bladders, and other equipment that need servicing. Best case this means water all over the place, worst case it means removing a section of the roof.

Proper freeze protection is a function of design for climate, and maintaining it is just part of maintaining a well. I've lived in moderate climate that all it required was a $15 thermostatically controlled receptacle adapter and a $20 heater. Now I live near Latitude 48N where we get months of freezing temperatures. My tank and well head are 8' below grade 6' x 6' concrete cell with an insulated shed above it, freezing is not a problem.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to put the pump house directly over the well if submersible pump. You have to provide an operable opening in the roof...as in removable skylight if (when) the pump needs to be pulled out and replaced. At best, it's awkward. Much easier out in the open where the pipe/pump assembly  can easily be lifted by a crane and the wires laid out on the ground.   Been there, done that.